# Building XML file in Perl: Relationship between createAttribute and addChild

Tags: xml, perl

I am learning to use `XML:LibXML` for a project in Perl and I saw [this example](http://justatheory.com/computers/programming/perl/xml-generation.html).

The goal is to build this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assets xmlns="http://bricolage.sourceforge.net/assets.xsd">
  <story id="1234" type="story">
    <name>Catch as Catch Can</name>
  </story>
</assets>
```

The author uses `addChild` to create `story` under `assets`:

```
my $story = $dom->createElement('story');
```

and he then **also** uses `addChild` (in combination with `createAttribute`) to specify the **attributes** for `story`:

```
$story->addChild( $dom->createAttribute( id => 1234));
```

Looking at the XML example above (without knowing much about XML), `id="1234"` is not a **child** of **story** but rather an attribute of it, so why do we use **addChild** in this last line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `createAttribute` or `createElement`, you create a new *node*. By calling `addChild`, you attach such a node into its parent. There are several types of nodes in XML: elements, attributes, but also text, comments, or processing instructions.

Answer (score 3):

An attribute is one type of child.

Comment: +1 This is a less complete answer than that of @choroba, but I think it's the one that answers my question most intuitively.

Comment: I agree with you. If that is what you think then you should accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

Since, `$story` is a [XML::LibXML::Element](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aElement), you might find it more natural to use the `setAttribute` method:

```
my $store = $dom->createElement('story');
$store->setAttribute(id => '1234');
```

which is a shorthand for longer `createAttribute` and `addChild` code you are doing.